# where is the location of client side git hooks in server

Tags: linux, git, server, gitlab

I want to deploy my own version of git client side hooks. for this, i need to know whether the client side hooks are generated from the clients system or are also cloned from the server.
If it is cloned from the server, what is the location where the client side hooks are located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client side hooks are not stored in server. Server has nothing to do with client side hooks in git. i.e. client side hooks and server side hooks are not inter-related. However, they are generated inside your local repository by your own local system.
In short, client side git hooks are not related to server and aren't stored there.

Answer (score 1):

The hooks location is under `.git` folder in your cloned folder

```
.git
├── branches
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── config
├── description
├── HEAD
├── hooks
├── index
├── info
├── logs
├── objects
└── refs
```

there is a folder `hooks`, where you can find `post`, `pre` hooks.

```
├── applypatch-msg.sample
├── commit-msg.sample
├── post-update.sample
├── pre-applypatch.sample
├── pre-commit.sample
├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
├── pre-push.sample
├── pre-rebase.sample
└── update.sample
```

rename .sample files to like `post-update.sample` to `post-update` to run `pre`, `post` hooks.